# div is in front of my login form?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my login form to be on top of the div that I'm using as a menu bar, but the div is in front and it's blocking the login form. This is the code I have right now, does anyone know how to fix this?:

```
#login-form {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#topbar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #336680;
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, put the `#login-form` element after the `#topbar` element. Logically, that's where it should be (which is useful for screen readers and text-only browsers)

Alternatively, use `z-index` in your CSS - a higher number gets put on top.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution to this would be to use `z-index` on `#topbar` and `#login-form` in your CSS. Elements with a higher `z-index` will be displayed on top of those with lower ones. This should work:

```
#login-form {
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#topbar {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #336680;
  box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```